# Help - Portable Recorder

Tags: portable-recorder, marantz, fostex

Marantz PMD 661 or Fostex FR-2LE ?

Comment: There's been a lot of discussion on recorders, did you use the search before posting?

Answer (score 2):

the 661 is a fix to the 660 which had rather bad rep. 
fr-2le is used by many professionals..

Answer (score 1):

Fostex FR-2LE .

Answer (score 1):

I was considering both of those recorders about 6 months ago. I think they would both be good. I was a little put off the fostex after reading that the battery capsule(thing) is attached by a wire, which over time and the wire being moved when changing batteries, may result in the wire eventually snapping. Otherwise it looked very suitable, and the sound quality is said to be above average for the category. I probably would have gone for the marantz though, simply for its greater portability, and from what I have read, it seems like a very good unit.

I ended up going with the sony pcm-d50, which due to the lack of xlr inputs (you can buy an expansion, but it's expensive and bulky), may put it out of contention. I love it, the in built mics sound great (so long as your expectations are within reason) and can be adjusted for varying results. It's very portable, meaning I actually have it at the ready almost everywhere I go. It's very sturdy, and the battery life is far superior to anything else I've seen. I intend on getting something like a sound devices unit when I have more cash, and use it for planned sessions, and keep the sony for any spontaneous opportunities I come across.

Oliver